# laravel memory limit error on apache2 ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ubuntu

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Allowed memory
>   size of 734003200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes)
>   in
>   /var/www/html/ProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:347

I am getting above error. I've tried increasing the `max_memory` in `php.ini`.

But still getting the error.

Comment: When this error occur?

Comment: // top of your controller
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

// Also you can increase memory
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');

Comment: It's worth looking at the code which is causing this, you can increase the limit but this may just hide an existing problem.

Comment: The error is clear - your script ran out of memory.  You should be looking at what code is doing that, and why?  Just increasing the memory available to it is not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First Edit your max_memory in php.ini than restart your apache2 with this command

```
service apache2 restart
```

Hope this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

the server was on EC2 instance. first i tried to increase the limit in php.ini file. My EC2 instace was t2.micro with just 1 GB of ram. I resized the EC2 instance to t2.small . also increased memory limit in php.ini. This solved the issue.